# AWS 100 TB data transformation at rest S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, etl

I have about 50 TB of data in an S3 bucket, the bucket doesn't have any partitioning. The files are json files approx 100KB each in size.

I need to do the partitioning on this data and put this in a different s3 bucket to store it in a structure of yyyy/mm/dd/filename.json or add a custom metadata field to the files which is the original lastmodifieddate on the file itself and move it to the different bucket.

I have looked into options like

1. Doing it with a spark cluster, mounting both buckets as dbfs and then doing the transformation and copy to destination bucket.
2. I have also tried writing a lambda function which can do the same for a given file and invoke it from another program. 1000 files take about 15 seconds to copy.
3. I also looked in to generating s3 inventory and running job on it but it's not customizable to add metadata or create a partition structure so to say.

Is there an obvious choice I may be missing or there are better ways to do it ?

Comment: Side-note: If this is a continuing need, you can use Amazon S3 Events to trigger the Lambda function so that the activity is done immediately after an object is created. This can be easier than doing it all in a batch.

Comment: Good idea @JohnRotenstein thats the idea, but for the data at rest its becoming a concern for me